# Unable to Rewrite on htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a few rules in htaccess that are working already however, when I try to add a seemingly simple RewriteRule it won't work.  I am just scratching my head. Basically I want to make

```
http://www.sample.com/dev/reference/library/a
```

into

```
http://www.sample.com/dev/library.htm?cat=a
```

The "a" can be any alphabets from a to z only.

I have htaccess like this:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^member/([A-Za-z0-9-_\s]+)/?$ member.htm?cid=$1 [NC]
    RewriteRule .....
    RewriteRule .....
    RewriteRule .....
    RewriteRule ^library/([A-Za-z])/?$ library.htm?cat=$1 [NC]
```

The library.htm sits on the root direct.  However, I am getting a "file not found" 404 error.  Any assistance is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.  It was looking for /dev/library and I had the files in /dev/reference/library.